# Sending html files to views

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a session controller like that

```
public function main_page() {

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $userID = $this->girismodel->girisKontrol($username, $password);


    $data = array();

    if (!$userID) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE);
        redirect('http://' . site_url() . 'giris/');
        $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('anasayfa/bLogin', '', true);
    } else {

        $this->session->set_userdata(array(
            'logged_in' => TRUE,
            'userID' => $userID,
            'username' => $username));

        $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('anasayfa/aLogin', '', true);

        redirect('http://' . site_url());
    }

    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
```

As you see on the above code, if session is not okay it loads to $data['menu'] = bLogin.php
else aLogin.php

After , i pass this to welcome_message and i try to use

```
echo $menu
```

i think it may be bullshit is there any other way? because it gives error:

```
Undefined variable: menu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting in both the conditions. Are you even getting the view welcome_message loaded!!! Remove those redirect line. As I see your code, you want to load the same view file with different `$data['menu']`. You dont need to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You have already redirected before setting $data['menu']

```
redirect('http://' . site_url() . 'giris/'); 
$data['menu'] = $this->load->view('anasayfa/bLogin', '', true);  <-- this will not execute
```